# HMS Cordova Push kit unsupported in Ionic 3.8

Tags: ionic-framework, huawei-mobile-services

I tried to create a sample project using Cordova HMS push kit in Ionic 3.8, it did not worked. It is working for Ionic 4 version but not working for version 3.8. Can anyone tell me how to make it work for version 3.8.

Comment: What sort of error are you receiving when you are trying to run the push kit on ionic 3.8?

If ionic 4.0 works, why are you wanting to use 3.8?

Are you following this guide: https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201235348685010075?fid=0101187876626530001 in integrating your app with the kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/ionic-intro-0000001050694986-V1?ha_source=hms1)，You are advised to update to version **4.0** or later.

[image]

If you still want to use version 3.8, you may need to contact Huawei Developer Technical Support Engineer(DTSE) to get support.